# Why does this algorithm run 20 times slower in Python than Java?

Tags: java, python

I've implemented the naive algorithm to compute all pythagorean triples for a given hypotenuse length in Java and Python. For some reason, the Python implementation takes ~20 times longer. Why is this the case?

```
$ time python PythagoreanTriples.py
[2800, 9600, 3520, 9360, 5376, 8432, 6000, 8000, 8000, 6000, 8432, 5376, 9360, 3520, 9600, 2800]
python PythagoreanTriples.py  13.92s user 0.71s system 87% cpu 16.698 total

$ time java PythagoreanTriples
[2800, 9600, 3520, 9360, 5376, 8432, 6000, 8000, 8000, 6000, 8432, 5376, 9360, 3520, 9600, 2800]
java PythagoreanTriples  0.32s user 0.12s system 72% cpu 0.618 total
```

The algorithm is to add `a` and `b` values to an output list in ascending order of `a` values and descending order of `b` values. Here are the Python and Java programs.

Python:

```
def pythagorean_triples(c):
    """

    :param c: the length of the hypotenuse 
    :return: a list containing all possible configurations of the other two
             sides that are of positive integer length. Output each
             configuration as a separate element in a list in the format a b
             where a is in ascending order and b is in descending order in
             respect to the other configurations.
    """

    output = []
    c_squared = c * c
    for a in xrange(1, c):
        a_squared = a * a
        for b in xrange(1, c):
            b_squared = b * b
            if a_squared + b_squared == c_squared:
                output.append(a)
                output.append(b)
    return output
```

Java:

```
public static Iterable<Integer> findTriples(int hypotenuse) {
    ArrayList<Integer> output = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    int c_2 = hypotenuse * hypotenuse;
    for(int a = 1; a < hypotenuse; a++) {
        int a_2 = a * a;
        for(int b = 1; b < hypotenuse; b++) {
           int b_2 = b * b;
           if(a_2 + b_2 == c_2) {
               output.add(a);
               output.add(b);
           }
        }
    }
    return output;
}
```

Comment: Python is interpreted. Java is a hybrid between compiled and interpreted. Purely interpreted languages are slower.

Comment: CPython has no JIT.

Comment: Related read http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/147089

Comment: the python version could be accelerated a little bit probably.

Comment: Yes, I definitely understand that Python being interpreted makes it slower (in general). I've used Python/Java for lots of tasks and usually the run-time disparity is *much* smaller. Why does Python perform so poorly specifically on the task above.

Comment: What makes you think it is performing poorly? A rough order of magnitude is about what you'd expect.

Comment: Unrelated to the question, but if `a` and `c` are known, can't you just calculate `b` instead of testing all possibilities?

Answer (score 1):

it seems most of the time is spent doing the multiplication:

because replacing

```
output = []
c_squared = c * c
for a in xrange(1, c):
    a_squared = a * a
    for b in xrange(1, c):
        b_squared = b * b
        if a_squared + b_squared == c_squared:
            output.append(a)
            output.append(b)
return output
```

by

```
all_b_squared = [b*b for b in xrange(1,c)]

output = []
c_squared = c * c
for a in xrange(1, c):
    a_squared = a * a
    for b_squared in all_b_squared:
        if a_squared + b_squared == c_squared:
            output.append(a)
            output.append(math.b)
return output
```

on my computer show a substantial gain in performance

also note that (on my computer)

- python3.4 is far slower than python2.7
- using `a**2` instead of `a*a` is significantly slower

I recommend you `vprof` and `pprofile` (`pip install vprof`) to profile line by line your method

it can be explained because `int` in python are a full object and not only a 32bit variable in your ram which will not overflow, at the opposite of the java integer.

Answer (score 0):

Python is not made for number crunching, but using a faster algorithm solves the problem in a few milli seconds:

```
def pythagorean_triples(c):
    """

    :param c: the length of the hypotenuse
    :return: a list containing all possible configurations of the other two
             sides that are of positive integer length. Output each
             configuration as a separate element in a list in the format a b
             where a is in ascending order and b is in descending order in
             respect to the other configurations.
    """
    output = []
    c_squared = c * c
    for a in xrange(1, c):
        a_squared = a * a
        b = int(round((c_squared - a_squared) ** 0.5))
        b_squared = b * b
        if a_squared + b_squared == c_squared:
            output.append(a)
            output.append(b)
    return output
```